# How can I add multiple on('click') methods in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, onclick

How can I add more than one function to be activated when click event is fired by jQuery?

E.g.:

```
$('body').on('click',myFirstFunction)
```

And I was wondering how to add more than one functions to be activated without the use of:

```
$('body').on('click',function(){
    myFirstFunction();
    mySecondFunction();

});
```

Comment: What's wrong with the second version?

Comment: The second one is actually the way to go! You could nest the second function call in the body of the first.

Comment: `$('body').on('click',myFirstFunction).on('click',mySecondFunction);`

Answer (score 4):

By simply attaching more than 1 **event handler** as you did in your code example.

```
$('body').on('click',myFirstFunction)
$('body').on('click',mySecondFunction)
$('body').on('click',myNthFunction)
```

Comment: Why would you not use chaining!?

Comment: because it is of no consequence to the answer.

Comment: *"no consequence"* Really? Your solution only causes extra DOM look-ups and extra jQuery object creation. `$(selector)` is not free.

Comment: that detail simply does not relate **to the question**. the point of the answer is to elaborate on the concept of multiple event handlers, not jquery selector efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

Also a possibility.

```
$('body').on('click',function() {
    myFirstFunction();
});

function myFirstFunction() {
    mySecondFunction();
}

function mySecondFunction() {
    myThirdFunction();
}

etc...
```